# Custom React Hook with callback is making closure

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I am trying to achieve is a custom hook that calls a callback on particular keypress. The thing is that the callback is dependant on component prop. Unfortunately callback is passed to the hook only once and it makes closure on prop value.

Hook Code:

```
export default function useKeyPress(targetKey, callback) {
  const keyPressedHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey && callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyPressedHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', keyPressedHandler);
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Component that uses a hook:

```
const Component = ({ isActive }) => {
  // isActive is changing here
  useKeyPress('ArrowRight', () => {
    if (isActive) // isActive always has the initial value 
      // do something if isActive is true
  });
}
```

How can I rewrite my hook or how should I handle this kind of situation?

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? Can you provide a complete usage example of the component

Comment: I think that provided code is sufficient to understand what my problem is. But in general I have like 3 page components that are stack one on another and all together they are a single page that can be navigated with scroll (steps, not continuous). This component is one of this pages. onKeyPress hook is used to change slides on this page, but when this particular page is not active I would like not to react on keypresses - that's why callback is dependant on prop (isActive).

Comment: I will probably try to not send the callback but instead, return if the key is pressed or not and then in the component where you use there I will use useEffect as a dependency will be the result from useKeyPress hook so if the key is pressed I will call function.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni That is also a possibility, but check the accepted answer. I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue on Codepen https://codepen.io/tedseds/pen/oNXzvoK

When you press arrow right it always logs `isActive` as false even when the prop is changed.

Solution https://codepen.io/tedseds/pen/ZEGpzPm

You need to pass prop `callback` as a dependancy to the `useEffect`.
It will reattach the event listener with the latest callback.

Code:

```
function useKeyPress(targetKey, callback) {
  const keyPressedHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey && callback && typeof callback === "function") {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyPressedHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", keyPressedHandler);
    };
  }, [callback]);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much :-)